# Use pandas groupby function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
Key    Departure    Species1   Species2   Status
1         R          Carlan     Carlan      D
1         R          Scival     Carex       C
2         R          Carlan     Scival      D
2         R          Scival     Bougra      C  
3         D          Carlan     Carlan      D
3         D          Scival     Scival      C
```

I want to count the occurrences of each unique `Species1` for a given `Departure` and `Status` of `D` of `C`

My desired output is:

```
Species1   RD    RC    DD    DC
Carlan     2     NaN   1     NaN
Scival     NaN   2     NaN   1
```

Comment: Just a suggesition, you might as well remove the bit about your function ```f(x)``` because you are not showing how you implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *pandas.crosstab()* method.  A single line of code:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Species1, [df.Departure, df.Status])
```

The resulting table:

[image]

If you combine with @dermen's 'comb' column,

```
df['comb'] = df.Departure + df.Status
pd.crosstab(df.Species1, df.comb)
```

you'll get:

[image]

If you *really* want those 'NaN', just tack on a `.replace('0', np.nan)`, like so (assuming an `import numpy as np` has already been done):

```
pd.crosstab(df.Species1, df.comb).replace('0', np.nan)
```

[image]

Comment: thats close enough, and I can rework it into what I need from there, thank! So simple...

Comment: @StefanoPotter-- Take a look at my edit.  I think it is _way_ better than my my previous answer, and it gets you what you want with just a couple very simple lines of code.

Comment: very interesting, never used crosstab before.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: nice. i will point out that numpy is by deafult imported with pandas, just try ```np = pandas.np```

Answer (score 3):

Make a new column that is the combination of Departure and Status

```
df['comb'] = df.Departure + df.Status
df
#  Key Departure Species1 Species2 Status comb
#0   1         R   Carlan   Carlan      D   RD
#1   1         R   Scival    Carex      C   RC
#2   2         R   Carlan   Scival      D   RD
#3   2         R   Scival   Bougra      C   RC
#4   3         D   Carlan   Carlan      D   DD
#5   3         D   Scival   Scival      C   DC
```

Then you can groupby:

```
gb    = df.groupby(['Species1', 'comb'])
gb.groups
#{('Carlan', 'DD'): [4],
#('Carlan', 'RD'): [0, 2],
#('Scival', 'DC'): [5],
#('Scival', 'RC'): [1, 3]}
```

Now organize the results into a list, where each element is a tuple `(column, Series(data, index))` representing a single data point in a new dataframe

```
items = [ (key[1], pandas.Series( [len(val)], index=[key[0]] ) )for key,val in gb.groups.items() ]
```

And make a new dataframe from the items:

```
result = pandas.from_items( items)
result
#        RC  DC  DD  RD
#Carlan NaN NaN   1   2
#Scival   2   1 NaN NaN
```

#### Extra info

See [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) for ideas on crating new dataframes from various objects. When you want to create a dataframe from individual data points (e.g. (Species1,comb) ), then `from_items` is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the a groupby query on multiple colums and and use the.agg function to count the number of occurences:

```
df.groupby(['Species1', 'Departure', 'Status']).agg(['count'])
```